# Concatenating index to string in JSTL, JSP

Tags: java, web, jstl, el

A **servlet sets request attributes** in a loop for each item that exists in a database, making it possible to call each item as shown below:

```
    ${UserWordPostUser0}
    ${UserWordPostUser1}
    ${UserWordPostUser3}
    ${UserWordPostUser4}
```

**However,** struggling to dynamically call each item in a loop. Any ideas why? Thanks for your time.

```
<c:forEach items="${resultsPostsArray}" var="wordposts" varStatus="count">

  <h6 class="caption" style="padding-left: 40px;">

  <a href="">

  ${UserWordPostUser}${index.count}      // does not work

  ${UserWordPostUser0}      //works

   </a>

  </h6>


  </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Because you can't build a variable name dynamically. Change to use an array.

Comment: @Andreas damn that sucks. Good to know. Your suggestion worked. Cheers.